# Why do baked textures turn out checkered or blocky?

Tags: texturing, materials, texture-baking

I've been having issues with baking textures recently and I have no clue how this happened and how to fix this. If anyone has suggestions or solutions I'll gladly accept them. Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXgqK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase/decrease that parameter before baking:
**Render - Baking - Ray Distance.** 
Begin with small ray amount - 0.1 or around it.
Also, some information from this video also can help:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r-cGjVKvGw

P.S. As i can judge by shape - you unwrapped your mesh properly? Re-check it, just to be sure.

Comment: I tried that, but I keep getting an error saying "No valid selected objects". Also I did check my unwrapped uv and I did fix it up just in case, but I still keep getting the checkered effect.

Comment: @Poke129 , let's try this:

1) Increase resolution value in UV/Image editor when creating and empty image for Normal Map, for example - 2048x2048;

2) Make sure that you've got your Low Poly mesh (on wich you are baking details) and High Poly one shares the same location;

3) That you selected low poly mesh LAST;

If it still doesn't help...
Open UV/Image editor, create new image for future Normal Map.
Node editor - create Image Texture node, don't connect it to anything, just select Normal Map image for it.
Switch off Select to Active and then Bake it. Try switching Tangent-Object.

Answer (score -1):

Did you use a cage? My solution was to recreate from the low poly mesh and it worked perfectly. I've applied the transforms, recalculated the normals and set the faces.  Btw, cage extrusion and max ray distance were set to zero.